# How to change javadoc view font color in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, colors, javadoc, foreground

[image: Java doc view looks like this]

Java doc shows like this,it seems font color is white,so how to change font color?

My configuration:

Ubuntu 12.10 64bit desktop
eclipse 4.2 classic theme

Comment: I have answered the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467359/how-to-change-the-textcolor-of-the-javadoc-view-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I manual added in /usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css   (I use the Theme "Mint-X", Ubuntu Menu -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Tab Theme )
After "@define-color **theme_**tooltip_fg_color #000000;" the following:

```
@define-color tooltip_bg_color #F6FBA0;
@define-color tooltip_fg_color #000000;
```

This worked for the background.
For some reason it doesn't worked for the foreground.
I tried setting nearly every variable without success.
At the end I set the Tooltip color hard-coded to #000000 in
/usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css (Line 2214: "color: #000000;"):

```
/***********
 * tooltip *
 ***********/

.tooltip {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid @border;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: @theme_tooltip_bg_color;
    color: #000000;
    box-shadow: none;    
}

.tooltip * {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Useful Info: Changes will only be applied after an Eclipse-Restart.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your are right.. JavaDoc seems to be white! You can check just making a change to the "font color" from your own JavaDoc to test it out, like this:

```
/**
 * <font color="white">This is some text with some color!</font>
 * 
 */
```

But this does not answer your question, so maybe you could look into:

- Window > Preferences > General > Appearance  --> Try to change your Theme and see if it works for you.

  or
- Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors And Fonts > Java > Javadoc View Background

It's not exactly the answer but it's a good start! And maybe being able to change you JavaDoc Background you could read all javadocs and keep up with the good work! ;P

Comment: Finally! I read any kind of comment to fix this: people that installed color scheme for the entire os, or editing random files around the eclipse installation.. but this is the only right answer... ! Thanks!